# Manga where a ghost on a rooftop can't move on until he finds out an art student loved him back

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's a Yaoi manga, very short, probably a one shot. The story goes that a lonesome guy goes to the rooftop and meets another guy lazing about there. He begins to talk to him and they soon begin to engage in sexual activities on the rooftop. As time passes, the main character comes to know more and more about the boy on the rooftop, and finds out that he used to be in love with an art student in his very school.

Basically the story ends with the main character finding out that the boy on the rooftop is actually the ghost of a guy who committed suicide, and helps him to leave the mortal world by showing him that the art guy did actually love him back, by showing him the portrait he painted of the rooftop guy.

Comment: I used baka updates and searched in categories. Beywedn yaoi and shounen ai.  I searched the genre of supernatural, school life. Some don't have a description but have tags with Ghost that might help you out. Looking at the cpvers might trigger your memory. 
Some have one shots in one volume. I know I have read the story but I can't recall it.       https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?genre=School+Life_Shounen+Ai_Supernatural&perpage=50
       https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?page=1&perpage=50&genre=School+Life_Supernatural_Yaoi&filter=completed

Answer (score 4):

It's called [*Kosha Ura no Natsu*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=105823) by Sakurabi Hashigo.

> Heartbroken Manabu-kun keeps meeting up with his senpai in the back of the school, who appears to be keeping a secret.

[image]

I've been looking for it too. I hope this helps someone!